# Gitlab - Enable the merge permission to reporter

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-8

I want to give the `merge_accept` permission to `reporters`. I know that I have to edit the policy file in the server. I edited the [project_policy.rb](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/app/policies/project_policy.rb) as below (added two lines)

```
rule { can?(:reporter_access) }.policy do
    enable :admin_merge_request
    enable :admin_project
  end
```

After adding this following line the reporter can able to merge the MR. But some how `developer` also getting the master permission.

Now how can I remove the `master` permission from developer?

Can anyone guide me to enable the merge accept permission to `reporter` alone?
I am using `GitLab CE 10.3.5`.

Comment: what changes have you tried so far?

Comment: @ArihantGodha I enabled the admin permission for merge request to Reporter what I mentioned in the question.